# Cannot retrieve blob data and display in JLabel- mySql

Tags: java, mysql, image, swing, inputstream

First time posting, hoping for some help. I have been through all similar postings on this forum...and believe the code used to be correct, however it continues to return nullpointerException. The program is a simple employee database, entering employee details along with picture. This is working fine, can insert image to blob field in mySql no problem. However, I simply cannot retrieve and display in JLabel.

The following code is the final part of the program, where the user can simply insert name of employee to retrieve all details. the search function is as follows:

```
void search(){
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        byte[] imageBytes;
        Image image;
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info WHERE pname='"+ txtSearch.getText() + "'");


        if(rs.next()){
            txtName.setText(rs.getString("Pname").toString());
            if (rs.getString("sex").toString().equals("Male")){
                cboGender.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }else{
                cboGender.setSelectedIndex(1);
            }

            txtAddress.setText(rs.getString("address").toString());
            txtPosition.setText(rs.getString("position").toString());
            txtSecurityLvl.setText(rs.getString("security").toString());

            try {
                String sql = ("select photograph from info where pname ='" + txtSearch.getText() + "'");
                ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    byte[] imagedata= rs.getBytes("photograph");
                    format=new ImageIcon(imagedata);
                    picLabel2.setIcon(format);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*
            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("photograph"));
                picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ByteStreams.toByteArray(Blob.getBinaryStream())));
             */



        }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not Found",null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);    
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help is is very much appreciated, this should be a simple task, but have been looking at it for so long that I cant see for looking. Thanks!

*nb- the mySql Db table is 'info', the column with containing blob is 'photograph'

Updated: The program should populate the respective textfields with name, address etc, and display the employee photo in a corresponding label. The textfields are populated but the program crashes at this line: picLabel2.setIcon(format); returning a nullPointerException () **line 630

Comment: What exactly in your program is not happenign as expected? Please indicate line numbers / quote some of the lines where the real issue is happening.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.search(test.java:630)
 at test$7.mouseClicked(test.java:521)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: The program should populate the respective textfields with name, address etc, and display the employee photo in a corresponding label. The textfields are populated but the program crashes at this line: picLabel2.setIcon(format);  returning a nullPointerException

Comment: Can you update your question with the requested information? That looks better as in a comment... And I see that it is in the search method on line 630, however I have no clue what line 630 is.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `picLabel2`. (Judging from the error)

Somewhere above `picLabel2.setIcon(format);`, you will need to do the following:

`JLabel picLabel2 = new JLabel();`

You may also still want to set text on the label, if that is required, then you can either:

- Pass it as `String` in the constructor.
- Call `picLabel2.setText(string)`.

Comment: Thanks skiwi, I have initialised the JLabel, and the program is no longer crashing, the textfields are being populated correctly, however the employee image still isn't being displayed :(

Comment: According to docs  .setIcon() method will not display anything if a null is passed...Can you suggest a way to test if a value is being received...? Thanks

Comment: My brain is mince...sorry...a value is being received: javax.swing.ImageIcon@4be3b5e0 ... so why is it not being displayed?? Thanks

Comment: `Creates an ImageIcon from an array of bytes which were read from an image file containing a supported image format, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG.` Is your image format one of those? Or what actually is your image format?

Comment: image file is .jpg, size is 16kb, format of mysql column is longblob...so shouldnt be a problem...

Comment: Can you suggest a better/alternative way to display blob data...?